# Fullcalendar JSON events custom start/end date

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, fullcalendar

I'm programming a functionality for Fullcalendar ( http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/ )

Can I see at the first renderings the agendaWeeks with customized start and end date using json?

I think that Fullcalendar automatically fits start and end values changing JSON url and pushing this 2 values.

I tried to force start, end vals (UNIX timestap) with a code like this, with no success.

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
   events: "json-events.php?start=132456543&end=245664532"
})
```

Analyzing Filezilla, the fullcalendar seems to duplicate the values. Any hint?

I would actually be able to see the corresponding week from a given day as input. I  therefore thought to calculate start and end timestamp.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the date the calendar should show after initialization, see http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/current_date/ for more information (date, month, year).

Adding the timestamps to the event source's url isn't the right thing to do, because that url will also be used to get the events in other dateranges.

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    date: 12,
    month: 4,
    year: 2012,
    events: 'json-events.php'
});
```